# Limit amount of viewers that can access a page

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I'm trying to figure out this problem for a while now. How would I limit the number of users allowed to view a page at once?

I should be able to limit access to the page like this:

```
if($numberViewers > 2) die("Too many viewers!");
```

Is this possible with **PHP and Javascript/jQuery?** (Sorry I don't have code at the moment, I'm pretty stumped on this one).

Thank you!

PS. Thank you "Dagon" for helping me in the other question, but I fixed my English on this one :)

---

I created a way to do this using several files:

First, when a user visits the page, `$_SESSION['username']` is appended to a file. When the user leaves the page, I used jQuery and Ajax to call to `leave.php?uid=$_SESSION['username']`. This works for my purposes, but is there an easier way to do this? I will leave it open for now, but if anyone has questions about my method of doing this, please post.

EDIT: Looking for answers that could work for several of these "restricted view pages".

Comment: How do you define users?

Comment: Unique visitors to the page. For example, unique $_SESSION['id'] would work.

Comment: You could keep a 'sessions' DB table, storing all the session IDs, and flag them with 'active', 'inactive', so this way you'd know at any given point in time, how many users are there.

Comment: The problem with that method Gabriel is that the site I am adding this to contains many users with many sessions, and not all of them will be viewing the page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want to do this with PHP/jQuery the best way is :
1. When an user is connecting to your app, add a row entry in a database via an AJAX call where you add the hour of connexion
2. Every x seconds, just make a new AJAX call to update the hour of connexion
3. When a new client is connecting, do 2 things : first, add a new entry to database, and after this, remove all entries in database which are under your x seconds period.

So, with this way, you know, when an user is connecting to your app, how many people are already connected to and you can die your message with this method.

(obviously, there is other ways to do this better, but not with PHP/Ajax if you want to know this dynamically).

Comment: But how would you know if the user left the page? It doesn't seem clear to me.

Comment: With the time you're registering in your database. If you update this time every x seconds, if when you check current date - date in db and the result is more than x seconds, so the user is gone.